# Permissions Enforced on Salesforce Apex WebService

Tags: permissions, salesforce, apex-code

After reading [this tidbit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm), it would seem that the current user's permission would be irrelevant. However when calling this method as anyone but a user with the Administrator profile, it throws an `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` exception:

```
global without sharing class OpportunityTeamSales {
    WebService static void AssignToSalesTeam(string userId, string opportunityId)
    {
        OpportunityTeamMember tm = new OpportunityTeamMember();
        tm.OpportunityId = opportunityId;
        tm.UserId = userId;
        tm.TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Engineer';

        insert tm;
    }
}
```

Event with the explicit `without sharing` keywords, it appears to be enforcing field-level security/permissions to the object/child object. `Opportunity` and `OpportunityTeamMember being` system objects, we can't edit the relationship.

**UPDATE:**

The user profile that is encountering the error has read/write/modify permissions on the `Opportunity` object and the `OpportunityTeamMember` object does not appear to have a specific permission set. We're simply trying to create an `OpportunityTeamMember`, the lookup target of which the user has full permissions to with the exception of "delete."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`without sharing` means that the class doesn't respect sharing rules, the rules which govern visibility of records within the system when the privacy setting for an object is set to `private`. As far as I'm aware it does not mean that object-level permissions are overridden, and so you can still not access a lookup field which joins to an object the user does not have access to, hence the error you're seeing here. You'll need to assign the user to a different user profile which does have access to these objects.

**EDIT**

Assuming your users do have the required access to the objects, I believe you also need the "Customize Application" permission checked on the user's profile for them to be able to modify sales teams.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've updated the question with more details on what we're trying to accomplish and what permissions the target user profile has.

Comment: Giving them the "Customize Application" does appear to fix the problem, although this is not something we want to allow. As it stands, it answers my question and we'll start pursuing other avenues for a solution that fits better. Thanks!